# Windows Mobile 6.5.3 development with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2015, windows-ce, windows-mobile-6.5

Does anyone know if there are any ways to allow Windows Mobile / Embedded Handheld 6.5.3 / CE development in Visual Studio 2015?

Seems only Windows Phone (Windows 10) dev is supported?

I am unable to find a copy of VS 2008 anywhere.

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possibile.
You may get VS2008 via MSDN or buying it from a windows embedded distributor.

Comment: Please look at VS2008 Profesional - it has the feature - SMART DEVICES.